# Is my file system dead?

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, live-usb

Yesterday I decided to update my system from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS.
I downloaded desktop ubuntu for i386 `.iso` and made a liveUSB(using UNetbootin). I choose `Try Ubuntu without installing` and there I run install and choosed `Update Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04`. And at the begining of the update system just stucked and I made reboot.

And now GRUB looks like this [image]

And when I try to choose ubuntu instead of loading it there appers messages like
[image]

I tried to check and fix partitions using GParted from LiveUSB and treid use `sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/partition_on_disk`. But all thing still the same. What else can help? Also I tried update GRUB but nothing changed too

Comment: what was your fsck output? what happens when you try to mount the partition? i'm in the same situation as you though, so don't hold out hope that i'm some guru with any answers :( By the way, what is 'fix'? I can't see any such command in Ubuntu, the repositories or google!

Comment: @Adam well it's not command, this is what fsck is asking you about :)

Comment: oh, sorry. i see what you mean. the way I read it, I thought you were using a seperate command. so does fsck fail when you run it? for my error, fsck says it's fixing the errors, but it actually doesn't and it ends with the message that the filesystem still has errors.

Comment: @Adam nope, I got the same - it was like it fixing errors but it didn't helped

Comment: Oh right. That's tough. It's weird that nobody is jumping in with more suggestions either on your Q or on mine. First of all we get a few answers, but then nothing. It's as if no-one wants to say definitively that the hardware is dead.

Comment: @Adamwell, my hdd fine I think. Becasue of windows 7 starter(when I bought my netbook it was installed) on it still works and works fine. And seems like all my files which I had on my 10.04 system are fine.

Comment: @Adam however, now I runned install ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot `ubuntu live usb` and run `install`.Don't choose update from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04,choose `something else` option.Select the ubuntu 10.04 partition and format it to `ext4 filesystem`.Then choose the same partition to install ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Are my files from 10.04 will be safe?

Comment: no,did you want to keep files in ubuntu 10.04 safe?Which files do you want to keep safe?

Comment: see this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: I mean I got some files on my `dev/sda5` where 10.04 were installed. If I install 12.04 on dev/sda5 are they will be lost?

Comment: yes they will be lost.

Comment: if you want to backup that `/dev/sda5` partition try `clonezilla`

Comment: Well, I coping right now my `/home` directory to my portable HDD drive (I used `sudo nautilus`)